# Laravel session token gets reset in Android Chrome Incognito mode post sign-in

Tags: android, google-chrome, laravel-5, mobile, incognito-mode

Recently we noticed a login issue in Android Mobile Incognito mode wherein post user sign in and on page reload, user signed-in state is not retained. We debugged this further and noticed that post login, request token and session token doesn't match i.e. session token gets reset. We suspect this is causing the sign in issue but we are not able to figure out what could be causing session token to be reset.

We tried adding new data to session using Session::put('key', 'value') post login but before page reload and then retrieve it on page load by Session::get('key') but it doesn't return the value set post login.

Following is the session(config/session.php) configuration:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'memcached'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 1440,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
| cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
| correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
|
*/

/*'store' => null,*/
'store' => 'memcached',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,
```

and RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapApiRoutes();
    Passport::routes();
    //
}

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}

protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

Laravel Version: 5.5.28

Any pointers on this issue or suggestions to debug would be helpful.